# Jenkins environment different to interactive logon - why?

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, windows-server-2012-r2

Using Jenkins 2.46.2 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have pipeline script that runs:

`bat 'env'`

I'm interested in environment variable: `PSModulePath`

This is output as

`PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`

in my console output. However, if I run this logged on as the Jenkins account on the Jenkins server, I get a different result:

`PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program File
s (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;C:\Program Files\Wind
owsPowerShell\Modules`

Why is that? I can't load some modules in a Jenkins job because they can't be found.

Comment: I worked around this by explicitly adding the path as an environment variable to Jenkins, but I don't know why I had to do that. Anyway it works now.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right values for PSModulePath?  The very first path in the PSModulePath for the Jenkins account is identical to the one (and only) path for your own account `(C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\)`.  If you were able to find the modules with your own account, they must be in that folder, and you should have found them under the Jenkins account as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by explicitly adding the path as an environment variable to Jenkins, but I don't know why I had to do that. Anyway it works now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out that Jenkins' [PowerShell Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin) runs as a 32bit process and does not see the modules installed in the 64bit `Program Files` folder.

Using the `ProgramW6432` env var fixes the problem.

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        // Add the 'real' ProgramFiles folder to the PSModulePath as the powershell is run as a 32bit process
        // and the modules are installed in the 'C:\Program Files\' folder
        PSModulePath = "${env.ProgramW6432}\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;${env.SystemRoot}\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules"
    }
...
```